# Magento 1.8 Customer login Confirmation key

Tags: magento-1.8, email, customer-account

Please help me to configure mail settings in Magento

http://grapixmedia.in/raj/test_mag/ = demo link

While Creating a new account as new customer, I gave in the

> System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration

Send

> Confirmation Key= Yes

But Account is getting created but the Confirmation key is not been sent to the mail which was given at the time of registration guyz please me

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your cache?
Seem it works fine.
[image: After login]

Comment: Did u check your mail did u get a mail

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get it. But it could be a mail sending problem. Could you check this (for example from contact us)?

Comment: I checked everythin bro... but couldn't figure out wat is the error

Comment: :) So, when you post a feedback via contact us form are you receiving an email into your valid email address which you set up in Admin Panel?

Answer (score 0):

Just override Account Controller...In magento like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dev_Customcustomer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Dev_Customcustomer>
    </modules>
    <!-- start of override Customer AccountController -->

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                    <customcustomer before="Mage_Customer">Dev_Customcustomer</customcustomer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>

    </frontend>

</config>
```

### in controllers

```
create AccountController.php

look this method..
class Dev_Customcustomer_AccountController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function confirmAction()
    {
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_getSession()->logout()->regenerateSessionId();
        }
        try {
            $id      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
            $key     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('key', false);
            $backUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back_url', false);
            if (empty($id) || empty($key)) {
                throw new Exception($this->__('Bad request.'));
            }

            // load customer by id (try/catch in case if it throws exceptions)
            try {
                $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
                if ((!$customer) || (!$customer->getId())) {
                    throw new Exception('Failed to load customer by id.');
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new Exception($this->__('Wrong customer account specified.'));
            }

            // check if it is inactive
            if ($customer->getConfirmation()) {
                if ($customer->getConfirmation() !== $key) {
                    throw new Exception($this->__('Wrong confirmation key.'));
                }

                // activate customer
                try {
                      // look this line from here 
                    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
                    $customer->save();
                    $customer->setStatus(1);
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
                     // to here 

                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw new Exception($this->__('Failed to confirm customer account.'));
                }

                $session->renewSession();
                // log in and send greeting email, then die happy
                $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $successUrl = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer, true);
                $this->_redirectSuccess($backUrl ? $backUrl : $successUrl);
                return;
            }

            // die happy
            $this->_redirectSuccess($this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true)));
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // die unhappy
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirectError($this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true)));
            return;
        }
    }

}

now this send confirmation mail to customer ......
```